# Angular 11 + Stripe Integration Issues and errors

Tags: angular, typescript, stripe-payments

I am facing an error while using ngx stripe with Angular

```
ERROR in src/app/payment/payment.component.html:19:24 - error TS2339: Property 'elementsOptions' does not exist on type 'PaymentComponent'.
19     [elementsOptions]="elementsOptions"

  src/app/payment/payment.component.ts:12:16
    12   templateUrl: './payment.component.html',
    Error occurs in the template of component PaymentComponent.
src/app/payment/payment.component.html:15:45 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.
15 <form novalidate (ngSubmit)="createToken()" [formGroup]="stripeTest">

  src/app/payment/payment.component.ts:12:16
    12   templateUrl: './payment.component.html',
    Error occurs in the template of component PaymentComponent.
src/app/payment/payment.component.html:17:3 - error NG8001: 'ngx-stripe-card' is not a known element:
1. If 'ngx-stripe-card' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngx-stripe-card' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

17   <ngx-stripe-card
18     [options]="cardOptions"
19     [elementsOptions]="elementsOptions"
20   ></ngx-stripe-card>

  src/app/payment/payment.component.ts:12:[93m16
    12   templateUrl: './payment.component.html',
    Error occurs in the template of component PaymentComponent.
src/app/payment/payment.component.html:18:5 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'ngx-stripe-card'.
1. If 'ngx-stripe-card' is an Angular component and it has 'options' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngx-stripe-card' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

18     [options]="cardOptions"

  src/app/payment/payment.component.ts:12:16
    12   templateUrl: './payment.component.html',
    Error occurs in the template of component PaymentComponent.
src/app/payment/payment.component.html:19:5 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'elementsOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'ngx-stripe-card'.
1. If 'ngx-stripe-card' is an Angular component and it has 'elementsOptions' input, then verify that it is part of this module.  
2. If 'ngx-stripe-card' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

19     [elementsOptions]="elementsOptions"

  src/app/payment/payment.component.ts:12:16
    12   templateUrl: './payment.component.html',
    Error occurs in the template of component PaymentComponent.
```

Now My Payment.component.html file looks like

```
<form novalidate (ngSubmit)="createToken()" [formGroup]="stripeTest">
  <input type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="Jane Doe" />
  <ngx-stripe-card
    [options]="cardOptions"
    [elementsOptions]="elementsOptions"
  ></ngx-stripe-card>
  <button type="submit">CREATE TOKEN</button>
</form>
```

And payment.component.ts file looks like

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {
  StripeCardElementOptions,
  StripeElementsOptions,
} from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import { StripeCardComponent, StripeService } from 'ngx-stripe';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-payment',
  templateUrl: './payment.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./payment.component.css'],
})
export class PaymentComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() total;
  @ViewChild(StripeCardComponent) card: StripeCardComponent;

  cardOptions: StripeCardElementOptions = {
    style: {
      base: {
        iconColor: '#111',
        color: '#111',
        fontSize: '1.2rem',
        '::placeholder': {
          color: '#111',
        },
      },
    },
  };

  elements: StripeElementsOptions = { locale: 'auto' };

  stripeTest: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    public activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private stripeService: StripeService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.stripeTest = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });
  }

  createToken(): void {
    const name = this.stripeTest.get('name').value;
    this.stripeService
      .createToken(this.card.element, { name })
      .subscribe((result) => {
        if (result.token) {
          // Use the token
          console.log(result.token.id);
        } else if (result.error) {
          // Error creating the token
          console.log(result.error.message);
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Ps: I have already done the import in app.module.ts under imports.

```
NgxStripeModule.forRoot('pk_test_TYooMQauvdEDq54NiTphI7jx')
```

Comment: Something wrong during package installation

Comment: @DarshanMalani I have installed it quite a few times on different pc, but the same issue persists

Comment: The ngx strripe examples do require the ReactiveFormsModule imported on your module.

Answer (score 0):

you can add inside module for your component

```
import { NgxStripeModule } from 'ngx-stripe'; //HERE
...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgxStripeModule.forChild(), // HERE
    ComponentsModule,
    NewPaymentMethodPageRoutingModule
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a line for the property definition for the  'elementsOptions'

```
ERROR in src/app/payment/payment.component.html:19:24 - error TS2339: Property 'elementsOptions' does not exist on type 'PaymentComponent'.
19     [elementsOptions]="elementsOptions"
```

You need to define elementOptions

this line should have elements named as elementOptions or change the databinding for where you pass it in

```
  elements: StripeElementsOptions = { locale: 'auto' }; //either change this to elementOptions
```

```
  <ngx-stripe-card
    [options]="cardOptions"
    [elementsOptions]="elementsOptions" // or change this ="options"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the below code inside your component where you are using elements options

```
import { StripeElementsOptions } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import { StripeService } from 'ngx-stripe';

constructor(private stripeService: StripeService) { }
card: any;
elementsOptions: StripeElementsOptions = {
    locale: 'en'
};

this.stripeService.elements(this.elementsOptions)
  .subscribe(elements => {
    this.elements = elements;

    // Only mount the element the first time
    if (!this.card) {
      this.card = this.elements.create('card', {
        style: {
          base: {
            iconColor: '#666EE8',
            color: '#31325F',
            lineHeight: '50px',
            fontWeight: 500,
            fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
            fontSize: '16px',
            '::placeholder': {
              color: 'rgb(107, 105, 105)',
              
            }
          }
        }
      });
      this.card.mount('#card-element');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am implement stripe payment gateway in my project. that time i faced this issue.

If someone facing this error and who use lazy loading in his project so please at once check your routing. Because I am facing same issue from last two days and then i found the problem in my routing.

Now my project works fine and this technique work for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a **child module** and the **component** is inside that child module then add the `NgxStripeModule.forChild()` in the **child module imports array**